# Ubuntu upgrade failed due to broken packages

Tags: package-management, upgrade, python, 22.04, purge

I tried to upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to version 22.04 but broken packages disrupt the upgrade process. The number of broken packages is high (70) and I can't remove all packages using *sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq* command. List of broken packages was attached.

```
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 < 20.04.0-3~ubuntu20.04.6 @ii mK > (< 21.04)
Broken libboost1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK >
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Breaks on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii mK > (< 3.37)
Broken libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken python3-pyqt5:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken libboost-system1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-system1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-serialization1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-serialization1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-date-time1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-date-time1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken libboost-chrono1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-chrono1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-atomic1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-atomic1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-thread1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-thread1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken libtss2-mu0:amd64 Breaks on libtss2-esys0:amd64 < 2.3.2-1 @ii mK > (< 3.0.1-2)
Broken python3-dev:amd64 Depends on python3.9-dev:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.4-0~)
Broken libboost-filesystem1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-filesystem1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libpython3-dev:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9-dev:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.4-0~)
Broken libboost-regex1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-regex1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libmaeparser1:amd64 Breaks on libschroedinger-maeparser1:amd64 < 1.2.2-1build1 @ii mK >
Broken python3-pyqt5.qtopengl:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (= 5.15.4+dfsg-3)
Broken gdb:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken libboost-test1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-test1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-context1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-context1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libgc1:amd64 Conflicts on libgc1c2:amd64 < 1:7.6.4-0.4ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-mpi1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-mpi1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python3-pyqt5.qtsvg:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (= 5.15.4+dfsg-3)
Broken python3-pymol:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR >
Broken python3-pyqt5.qtxmlpatterns:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (= 5.15.4+dfsg-3)
Broken libboost-fiber1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-fiber1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python3-pyqt5.qtsql:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (= 5.15.4+dfsg-3)
Broken libboost1.74-tools-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.71-tools-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK >
Broken python3-pyqt5.qtwebchannel:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (= 5.15.4+dfsg-3)
Broken libboost-type-erasure1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-type-erasure1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-graph-parallel1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-graph-parallel1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-random1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-random1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (= 5.15.4+dfsg-3)
Broken libboost-exception1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-exception1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libnode72:amd64 Breaks on libnode64:amd64 < 10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1 @ii mK >
Broken libboost-log1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-log1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-container1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-container1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-timer1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-timer1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-wave1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-wave1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-math1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-math1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-locale1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-locale1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-coroutine1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-coroutine1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-numpy1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-numpy1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK >
Broken pymol:amd64 Depends on python3-pymol:amd64 < 2.3.0+dfsg-1build1 | 2.4.0+dfsg-3 @ri umR >
Broken libboost-python1.74-dev:amd64 Depends on python3-dev:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ri umR >
Broken python3-pyqt5.qtquick:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (= 5.15.4+dfsg-3)
Broken libboost-program-options1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-program-options1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python3-pyqt5.qtpositioning:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (= 5.15.4+dfsg-3)
Broken libboost-stacktrace1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-stacktrace1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-graph1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-graph1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (= 5.15.4+dfsg-3)
Broken python3-openbabel:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (= 5.15.4+dfsg-3)
Broken libboost-iostreams1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-iostreams1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libboost-mpi-python1.74-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-mpi-python1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken sssd-ad:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (>= 2:4.13.5+dfsg)
Broken plip:amd64 Depends on python3-openbabel:amd64 < 3.0.0+dfsg-3ubuntu3 | 3.1.1+dfsg-6ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken sssd-ipa:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (>= 2:4.13.5+dfsg)
Broken nvidia-cuda-toolkit-doc:amd64 Breaks on nvidia-cuda-doc:amd64 < 10.1.243-3 @ii mK > (< 10.2.89-3)
Broken libomp5-13:amd64 Conflicts on libomp-x.y:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken torbrowser-launcher:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR >
Broken sssd-ad-common:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (>= 2:4.13.5+dfsg)
Broken libboost-mpi-python1.74.0:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-mpi-python1.71.0:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python3-qtpy:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR >
Broken libomp-10-dev:amd64 Depends on libomp5-10:amd64 < 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1)
Broken nvidia-cuda-gdb:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken idle-python3.8:amd64 Depends on python3.8-tk:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libavresample4:amd64 Depends on libavutil56:amd64 < 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 -> 7:4.4-6ubuntu5 @ii umU > (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1)
Broken gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 Depends on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii mR > (= 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken libopenbabel6:amd64 Depends on libschroedinger-maeparser1:amd64 < 1.2.2-1build1 @ii mR >
Broken persepolis:amd64 Depends on python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.4+dfsg-3 @ri umR > (>= 5.5)
Broken libmetacity1:amd64 Depends on metacity-common:amd64 < 1:3.36.1-1 -> 1:3.40.0-1 @ii umU > (= 1:3.36.1-1)
Broken gvfs-bin:amd64 Depends on gvfs-common:amd64 < 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 -> 1.47.91-1ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1)
Broken libboost-python1.71-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.71-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 @ii mR > (= 1.71.0-6ubuntu6)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1)
Broken sssd:amd64 Depends on sssd-ad:amd64 < none | 2.4.1-2ubuntu4 @un uH > (= 2.4.1-2ubuntu4)
Broken vlc-plugin-samba:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libboost-python-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-python1.74-dev:amd64 < none | 1.74.0-8ubuntu6 @un uH >
Broken libboost-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-python-dev:amd64 < 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 | 1.74.0.3ubuntu6 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on libwbclient0:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 -> 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ii umU > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 @ri umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 | 2.3.1-2ubuntu2 @ri umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 -> 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 @ri umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken gvfs-backends:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.12.0+dfsg)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:40.0-1ubuntu5 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:40.0-1ubuntu5 @ii umR >
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on libpython3.9:amd64 < none | 3.9.7-2build1 @un uH > (>= 3.9.1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on libwbclient0:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 -> 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ii umU > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 @ri umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 | 2.3.1-2ubuntu2 @ri umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 -> 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 @ri umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:40.0-1ubuntu5 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:40.0-1ubuntu5 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.472 @ii umR NPb >
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center-data:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 -> 1:40.0-1ubuntu5 @ii umU > (< 1:3.37)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 @ri umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 | 2.3.1-2ubuntu2 @ri umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken python3-brlapi:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-numba:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-biopython:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-bottleneck:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 -> 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken python3-reportlab-accel:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-reportlab:amd64 Depends on python3-reportlab-accel:amd64 < 3.5.34-1ubuntu1 | 3.5.66-1 @ii umH > (>= 3.5.66-1)
Broken python3-cutadapt:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken duplicity:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-protobuf:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-ruamel.yaml.clib:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-dnaio:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-stl:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-pyxattr:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-sss:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-wxgtk4.0:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-cffi-backend:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken python3-pygame:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9~)
Broken playonlinux:amd64 Depends on python3-wxgtk4.0:amd64 < none | 4.0.7+dfsg-11 @un umH > (>= 4.0.7+dfsg-3~)
Broken idle:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.9.4-1build1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.9.4-1build1)
Broken python3-ruamel.yaml:amd64 Depends on python3-ruamel.yaml.clib:amd64 < none | 0.2.2-1build1 @un ugH >
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.1-2ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 -> 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken sssd-common:amd64 Depends on python3-sss:amd64 < none | 2.4.1-2ubuntu4 @un ugH >
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2 @ri umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken sssd-krb5-common:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.4.1-2ubuntu4 @un ugH > (= 2.4.1-2ubuntu4)
Broken sssd-ldap:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.4.1-2ubuntu4 @un ugH > (= 2.4.1-2ubuntu4)
Broken sssd-proxy:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.4.1-2ubuntu4 @un ugH > (= 2.4.1-2ubuntu4)
Broken sssd-krb5:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.4.1-2ubuntu4 @un ugH > (= 2.4.1-2ubuntu4)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 | 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 @ri umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2)
```

Comment: I've delete my answer, since it wasn't investigated thoroughly. @pilot6 mentions:
`There is an official path from one LTS to another, but it is not officially opened yet. So the "optimal cycle" would be to wait till 22.04.1 is released and then upgrade directly`

Comment: @kanehekili Ubuntu 22.04 is released, why it is not officially opened?